# jvectormap customzing the Usa map

Tags: jvectormap

We are using jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js file for displaying JVectorMap USA map.
The requirement is that we need to show north california and south california in place of california.where can i find the Jvectormap coordinates for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either of the two way:

1. Get or generator a map/shapefile for USA with North and South California and then generate `.JS` file using `Converter.py`
2. It would be a manual effort but since you need to do it just for one state you can do it. i.e., create copy of California in `js` file call old copy as North California and new copy as South California and read/modify `Path` attribute to make it work.